# Understanding simple array logic for itemDetails(itemNo) = {size/colour/quantity} in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, indexing

Can you help me with this array logic and how to put it together simply in javascript? Thanks!

```
//hidden array data
var itemNo = 0;
var itemDetails[itemNo]= {size:"big", colour:"yellow", quantity:5};
var itemDetails[itemNo+1]= {size:"small", colour:"blue", quantity:3};
var itemDetails[itemNo+2]= {size:"smaller", colour:"red", quantity:8};

//Allow user to change any of the details held about a single item
itemNo = 2;  //eg
itemDetails[itemNo].colour = "yellow"   //use sets item2's colour value


//List details of all items held
echo Here's an overview of details stored about each item

        Size   Colour   Quantity
Item 0: big     yellow       5
Item 1: small    blue        3
Item 2: smaller  yellow      8
echo There are no more items to list.
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by simply?  That seems pretty simple so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first declare `itemDetails`:

```
var itemDetails = [];
```

If you want to, you can put the objects in the array when you declare it:

```
var itemDetails = [
    {size:"big", colour:"yellow", quantity:5},
    {size:"small", colour:"blue", quantity:3},
    {size:"smaller", colour:"red", quantity:8}
];
```

If you still want to use `itemNo`, you can, but it's unnecessary as you could just use numbers. In any case, only use `var` when you're declaring a variable. Otherwise, omit it because you're just making an assignment:
`itemDetails[itemNo]= {size:"big", colour:"yellow", quantity:5};
itemDetails[itemNo+1]= {size:"small", colour:"blue", quantity:3};
itemDetails[itemNo+2]= {size:"smaller", colour:"red", quantity:8};`

In review, here is your corrected program (with `itemNo`):

```
var itemDetails = [];
itemDetails[itemNo]= {size:"big", colour:"yellow", quantity:5};
itemDetails[itemNo+1]= {size:"small", colour:"blue", quantity:3};
itemDetails[itemNo+2]= {size:"smaller", colour:"red", quantity:8};

itemNo = 2;
itemDetails[itemNo].colour = "yellow";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Noble. After trying that, and playing around with a few other styles of array, the simplest I've settled on - and which may help people get going with creating a simple shopping cart - is:

```
var item = 0;  //current index reference

var size = ["big", "medium", "small"];
var colour = ["green", "blue"];
var quantity = [3, 1, 20];

//cart contains
alert(size[item] + colour[item] + quantity[item]);
alert(size[item+1] + colour[item+1] + quantity[item+1]);
//etc


//update item page
item = 1;  //current index reference
size[item] = "bigger";  
colour[item] = "purple";  
quantity[item] = "100";  



//cart now contains
alert(size[item] + colour[item] + quantity[item]);
alert(size[item+1] + colour[item+1] + quantity[item+1]);
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Well, it might actually be better if you keep the size, color, and quantity of something in one object like you did before because making isomorphic arrays might not be reliable if you make a mistake and it'll probably be easier to read and work with your code if you use objects in this situations. In practice, this still works, but you just might want to get used to using objects. Just a suggestion.